# Can having large executables hurt performance?

Tags: caching, x86, executable, instructions

Fewer instructions are faster since more of them can be fit into the instruction cache at the same time.

I know that having fewer instructions in a loop can improve performance, but how much does the size of the executable impact performance? Would there be any appreciable difference in performance if an executable is 15mb in size compared to another that does the same operations but is only 5mb in size?

I ask this because I recently came across an executable that is 180mb in size and I'm curious as to whether or not that negatively impacts performance due to the instruction cache.

Comment: Instruction caches are *very* small, relatively speaking, so a 5 MB vs 15 MB vs 180 MB executable won't matter in terms of the i-cache. What might matter is whether the entire thing fits into (physical) memory, or has to be constantly swapped between memory and disk (page file/virtual memory). Computers generally have enough memory now that a 180 MB executable would fit entirely in physical memory, and thus wouldn't really have any effect on performance. Of course, there could certainly be *other* effects on performance, like why is the code so damn bloated that the binary is > 100 MB?

Comment: Maybe the reason that executable is so large is because it has embedded resources (bitmaps, icons, cursors, sounds, etc.) that the code loads at various times. In that case, the size really wouldn't matter, since the resources would only be loaded when they are needed, and they wouldn't all be needed at the same time. The *executable code* would certainly be small enough to fit entirely within physical memory, and maybe even in an L2/L3 cache. All of this to say, it depends, and the answer is complicated, and we really need more information to give a good answer.

Comment: Just look at the masters of compression - the demoscene. That code can fit into L1 about 16 times and there is probably no noticable increase in speed compared to something around 2 MB. Modern OS is usually pretty good about caching everything and the compilers very often do their job pretty good. If we're talking about huge binaries, the resulting speed also depends on the packer used to put it together. As @CodyGray says, it's a hell of a complicated matter. Fun excercise in c++: `char a[1024*1024*64]={7};int main(){return 0;}` makes ~67kb binary.

Comment: Demoscenes have a different goal, they prioritize size over all else because they are so size-constrained. That's just the classic optimization tradeoff for speed vs. size. For example, do you load a register with `mov eax,6`, or do you do `push 6`+`pop eax`? The latter is fewer bytes, but slower. The other obvious example is unrolling and vectorization. Plenty of ways to make things faster by making the code larger. So not really a fair argument. Also, I don't see why that exercise would be fun or surprising. Data takes up space in the binary, too. If not accessed, it takes no cycles, though.

Comment: @CodyGray I agree wholeheartedly. Just wanted to point out that size doesn't matter and the main speed culprit is always the bubble sort running in background.